# Slow scrolling on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I have a website that sells sneakers, **On all the pages** the scrolling is immensely slow.

The source code is [here](http://www.nickskicks.tk/?edit=css)
The actual Website is [here](http://www.nickskicks.tk/)

I have removed `background-cover` as suggested, but its still laggy. I have 3 `JavaScript`
files which are `head.load.min.js`, `head.min.js`, `head.js`, and `echo.js`

The `head.js` files are to help the page load faster(i'm not sure if I need all of them though) the `echo.js` is a very simple JS file that makes it easier to output text.

That's the only code causing the problem as far as I can tell.

You can find the full source code for the css file [here](http://nickskicks.tk/style/full)

I also have 2 php file includes: one for ads, second for displaying products on the page.
I have only used 7.38MB of 1500MB disk space

I also have the site setup with CloudFlare,
[DISREGARD THIS]:
 but it never shows the cache files in the source? Could someone also explain how the CDN system works if possible(but not required at all by any means)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You need to provide relevant information. What page is slow? Works fine for me

Comment: @ZachSaucier check again

Comment: @ZachSaucier at the top I stated that it is laggy on ALL Pages

Comment: All scrolling works fine for me but shopping seems to be the only page that has enough content to scroll

Comment: @ZachSaucier what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, firefox, and ie11 on win 7

Comment: Same but mine on all pages is laggy. But only on my site. What do you think could be the problem? @ZachSaucier

Comment: It's possible your PC can't handle it (though kind of doubtful). Can't say because I don't see it

Comment: I dont think so, it runs other things that use a high amount of graphic resources @ZachSaucier

Comment: Doesn't seem to be laggy to me using chrome, ff, ie11 on win 8 and safari (iPhone)

Comment: Ok, then I'll have to do some trouble shooting @BenEgan1991

Comment: Just to remind you, you have some errors on the pages: check meta tag for initial-scale, and on the bottom of the page you cannot pass php file to script element.

Comment: And I think that head.min.js causes the problem. Try to exclude that script tag and see what happens.